# group magento products under subcategories on a parent category page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When someone clicks on a parent category page I want all the products listed there to be divided by their child categories, such as the following:

(clicking on parent category 'apparel')

Shirts:
[shirt #1] [shirt #2] [ shirt #3]

Pants:
[pants #1] [pants #2] [pants #3]

Socks:
[socks #1] [socks #2] [socks #3]

The setup I have is the parent category 'apparel' has three children 'shirts', 'pants', and 'socks'. When the 'apparel' category page is shown it just lists all products without grouping them under their respective subcategories.

I am using Magento Community 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

Get all child categories

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId); 
$all_child_categories = $category_model->getResource()->getAllChildren($_category);
```

Get all the category's products

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                       ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

**Edit:**

In order to get subcategory products follow these steps:

Go to this template file (here is where you can put all the code listed below):

```
catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Get the current category ID:

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$currentCategoryID = $currentCategory->getEntityId();
```

Load the current category model to get the category children:

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryID);
```

Get all the child category id's:

```
$all_child_categories = $category_model->getResource()->getAllChildren($category_model );
```

Loop through each child id and load the category and it's children:

```
foreach ($all_child_categories as $child_id):
    $child_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child_id);
    $products =  Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                   ->addCategoryFilter($child_cat);
endforeach;
```

Let us know if yo need further assistance

Comment: do I need to loop through $all_child_categories and call $productCollection by each?

Comment: I am including $all_child_categories in catalog\product\list.phtml and it returns with an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getResource() on a non-object in...

Comment: whoops forgot to add this: $category_model =  Mage::getModel(’catalog/category’);

Comment: hmmm... now I get the error:Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreId() on a non-object in ...\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Flat.php on line

Comment: you need to pass the actual $category object (not just an id) in the second function. to do this use this coded to load the $category object $category_object = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);

Comment: sorry. I keep on getting errors. I really need to take some time to learn this system in depth. If you know of any good articles explaining the php classes and when they can be called, please tell me. thank you.

Comment: sure, go to training.magento.com and signup for a free user account - they have tons of video (for free) explaining all the important parts

Comment: ok. there seems to have been some progress. Only that It shows empty product (I have two confugurables and it only shows the associated products). Could this be due to the "$this->..." and "$helper->..." used in displaying the products as they are looped through?

Comment: probably, maybe paste the code somewhere so that we can both review and see what's happening

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22187/discussion-between-ywsw-and-pzirkind)

Comment: pzirkind, have you created the file yet? I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: yes :) here is the new code: http://pastebin.com/mbUBr1bn there is possibly another way of achieving your goal (without any coding), this is to make the parent category an 'anchor' category see this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/15810/

Comment: another link with more info: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-and-managing-categories

Comment: thank you very much!! I am still not getting any product pictures, names, prices - only blank image placeholders. Although the URLs seem intact. Is it possible that ->addCategoryFilter($child_cat) does not load all the information of the products?

Comment: ->addCategoryFilter($child_cat) also seems to show products which are set to no visibility

Comment: use ->getProductCollection(); instead :)

Comment: yes, i forgot to loop through each product in $productCollection, if you have a problem doing that let me know

Comment: $_productCollection =  Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->getProductCollection($child_cat);       shows fatal error of undefined...

Comment: ah, do this $category_model->getProductCollection();

Comment: $_productCollection = $category_model->getProductCollection($child_cat); shows all products (even those set to no visibility), without pictures, names, or price. Also, it gives the same products for all subcategories.

Comment: strange... this is the same method used by magento on the top of the page. maybe you need to make sure it's inside the loop

Comment: on the top of the page magento uses ->getLoadedProductCollection; could it have something to do with Mage::getResourceModel('**catalog/product_collection**')  ?